# How do I get rid of the square brackets after the code is implemented?

Tags: java

I was doing this question for an assignment where we had to add two matrices element by element and this was the output:

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] 
[0] 14  14  15  11  
[1] 8   9   14  11  
[2] 10  18  7   16  
[3] 4   12  11  8
```

My main question is how do I get rid of the square brackets that show up on the top and left side of the matrix. Here is the code:

```
    package question1;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Question1 {
    public static void initialize(int[][] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){          
            for(int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++){
                a[i][j] = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9);
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }               
    }

    public static int[][] sum(int[][] a, int[][] b) {       
        int[][] result = new int[a.length][a[0].length];        
        for(int row = 0; row<a.length; row++){          
            for(int col = 0; col<a[row].length; col++){
                result[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col];
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }

    public static void printArray(int[][] a) {
        System.out.println("\t");
        for (int col=0; col<a[0].length; col++) {
            System.out.print("[" + col + "]\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
        for (int row=0; row<a.length; row++) {
            System.out.print("[" + row + "]\t");
            for (int col=0; col<a[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(a[row][col] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the rows and columns for the first matrix (row followed by columns):");
        int row1 = keyb.nextInt();
        int col1 = keyb.nextInt();
        int[][] c1 = new int[row1][col1];
        System.out.println("Your first matrix is:");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        initialize(c1);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter the rows and columns for the second matrix (row followed by columns):");
        int row2 = keyb.nextInt();
        int col2 = keyb.nextInt();
        int[][] c2 = new int[row2][col2];
        System.out.println("Your second matrix is:");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        initialize(c2);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The sum of your arrays are:");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        int [][] result;
        result = sum(c1, c2);
        printArray(result);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework questions are frowned upon here, but I'll give you a hint...think about which statements print output to the console...

Comment: @ironicaldiction Homework questions are completely fine, *as long as they are on topic*. In this case the OP did little to solve the problem he was facing.

Comment: If you ever want to get any good at programming, maybe study the code, actually try. This is almost too obvious. Get rid of lines like `System.out.print("[" + col + "]\t");` and `System.out.print("[" + row + "]\t");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your `printArray()` method to use spaces in place of the brackets for the column and row headers:

```
public static void printArray(int[][] a) {
    System.out.println("\t");

    for (int col=0; col < a[0].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(" " + col + " \t");  // use spaces instead of brackets
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int row=0; row < a.length; row++) {
        System.out.print(" " + row + " \t");  // use spaces not brackets

        for (int col=0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(a[row][col] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```